# iron-ajax GET returning bad request

Tags: jquery, polymer

I'm using the polymer starter kit and I configured app.js file so it creates and iron-ajax element and send a call to the server to get data.
Here is the code:

```
var _ajax = document.createElement('iron-ajax');
    _ajax.url = 'url';
    _ajax.headers = '{ "Authorization": "auth (number)"}';
    _ajax.method = 'GET';
    _ajax.handleAs = 'json';
    _ajax.debounceDuration = 300;
    _ajax.auto = true;
```

The error returned from this code tells me that "Authorization" in the headers is not passed through, but when I console log the iron-ajax element before the request I can see "Auth" in the headers.
Am I doing something wrong in this code? What's the right way so the headers actually pass my server authentification.
Note: tested the server with google "advanced REST api" it works fine with "Auth" set in the headers. (using slim php for REST server)

Answer (score 1):

`headers` expects an object, not a JSON string representing an object:

```
var _ajax = document.createElement('iron-ajax');
    _ajax.url = 'url';
    _ajax.headers = {"Authorization": "auth (number)"};
    _ajax.method = 'GET';
    _ajax.handleAs = 'json';
    _ajax.debounceDuration = 300;
    _ajax.auto = true;
```

Comment: Thx for ur response. That's what I supposed, but gave me the same error (Bad request) based on "Auth" not being visible in headers. So I took a look at iron-ajax docs and got this: `<iron-ajax
    auto
    url="http://somesite.com"
    headers='{"X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"}'></iron-ajax>`check headers.
By the way, that's server side `$headers = apache_request_headers();
    if (isset($headers['Authorization'])) {
        // some code
    } else {$response['meta']["error"] = true;
       // some code
        echoResponse(400, $response);
        $app->stop();
    }`

Comment: When you set it via the HTML attribute then you use a JSON string representation of the object, which Polymer will cast to an `Object`.  If you are setting it via the property in Javascript, then you can pass it an `Object` directly.

Comment: Oh, ok didn't catch that. Thx for clarifying, but still facing the issue with the bad request. According to the server code I'm supposed to get error 400 only if $headers['Authorization'] isn't set. Don't get it

Comment: I got it working for some reasons, "Authorization" works when it's lower case. Don't know why, but I'll be glad to know